# On the meaning of 場になって思う

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence

> 今この立場になって思うのは世の中で「女性活躍」ってすごく言ってるじゃないですか

The first question is why te form is used in になって? is it to connect it to 思う?

Does すごく言ってるじゃないですか means to speak a lot bout women empowerment ?

full context https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/news_seminar/senpai/senpai3/?utm_int=news_contents_special_003
でも、出世はしてみるといいと思います。
今この立場になって思うのは、世の中で「女性活躍」ってすごく言ってるじゃないですか。
これって女性たちにとっては、すごいチャンスなんですよ。
はい。
もし誰もやらなかったら、多分次につながる女性の道は作っていけない…自分がやりたいからというよりも、みんなのためにそういう道を作っておく必要があると思って決めたんです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Question 1

> The first question is why te form is used in になって?

#### Parsing: 場になって思う

You've misparsed this a bit.  In this excerpt from your sample text, I've bolded the relevant portion.

> 今この**立場になって思う**のは

So it's not 場【ば】になって, but rather 立場【たちば】になって.

#### The meaning: 今この立場になって思うのは

A 立場【たちば】 is literally a 立【たち】 ("standing") 場【ば】 ("place") -- where someone or something stands.  Much like the English expressions "standpoint" or "where [someone] stands", this Japanese term 立場【たちば】 has an extended range of meanings that includes "perspective, stance, position on something".

This なって doesn't translate directly into English.  In this context, it's used with the basic meaning of "to become", and it describes how the general situation has turned out: *"[the situation] has **become** now, in this place, and then [other clause]..."*  Idiomatically, it's more like "now that things have developed *to this point*, ..."

As such, the fuller phrase:

> 今【いま】この立場【たちば】になって思【おも】うのは

... could be understood as something like:

*"So now, in this standing/situation, what [I] think is ..."*

As for why specifically the ～て form is used, here this is used as a conjunction, to join the preceding phrase to the next one.

### Question 2

> Does すごく言ってるじゃないですか means to speak a lot bout women empowerment?

Essentially, yes.  In context, we can see more about the actor of the verb 言ってる:

> **世の中で**「女性活躍」ってすごく言ってるじゃないですか。

So **in society at large**, this is being talked about a lot.

---

Please comment if the above does not address your questions.

Comment: So putting them together it becomes....   ? Thanks for the answer by the way .